# Amplitude demodulation of sinusidal signal in matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab, discrete-signals, lowpass-filter, demodulation

AM-demodulation task and I was asked to demodulate the signal in MATLAB and the result should contain three pictures.

plotting the $fft$ the (frequency spectrum)of the signal i was able to determine that the pictures are located at 0.1 , 0.25 and 0.5 frequencies.

The problem is that my code below only plot one picture which is located at 0 and I don't know how plot the shifted pictures that are located at 0.25 and 0.5 frequencies.

I tried to multiply it by complex exponential and still not able to plot the pictures

The main problem is that i need to shift those pictures that are located at 0.25 and 0.5 frequency to the center and apply my low pass filter, however i tried as the following code but failed. please help me.

The is the $fft$ of the signal.

[image]

> I get a mysterious signal modulated with the message as a signal vector `z[n]`,
>   by running the MATLAB function `mkhwdata`. The parameters of this function are your
>   social security number in one
>   column vector, e.g.
>   `z = mkhwdata ([xxxxxx]);`
>   The response from the function will be that a vector z containing the signal z[n], where the vectors
>   first element corresponds to the time index n = 0.
>
> • To convert a vector, e.g. vector `s` describing the signal `s[n]`, to an image use the provided function `present_image`. Try for example to watch the signal `z[n]`
>   directly:
>   `present_image (z)`

```
clc
close all;
clear

fc = 0.2;
fs = 0.5;
[z]= mkhwdata([xxxxxxxxx]);

[Z,nu] = tdftfast(z);
%N = length(z);
 n = [-0.5:1/0.5:0.5];
%n = N*(0:N-1);
 mult  = 0.5.*exp(1i*2*0.25*pi.*n)  + 0.5.*exp(-1i*2*0.25*pi.*n);
 mult2 = 0.5.*exp(1i*2*pi*0.5.*n)   + 0.5.*exp(-1i*2*pi*0.5.*n);
 [z1] = ifft(Z.*mult);

 [z2] = ifft(Z.*mult2);

 %Lowpass filter
 [num,den] = butter(9,0.2);

 y  = filter(num,den,z);
 y1 = filter(num,den,z1);
 y2 = filter(num,den,z2);
 figure(4)
 ylabel('Amplitude');
 xlabel('Frequency (hz)');
 subplot(221)
 present_image(z);
 subplot(222)
 present_image(y);
 subplot(223)
 present_image(y1);
 subplot(224)
 present_image(y2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some problems with your analysis structure.

First of all, for being able to see from -0.5 to 0.5, without aliasing, you have to sample at 1.

Secondly, if you want to down convert a signal, bring it to DC you need to multiply it with the corresponding cosine in time, or discrete time, or apply the convolution to its spectrum with the corresponding Fourier transformed cosine (a cosine in spectrum is a delta Dirac function on the frequency of the same cosine).

By the way, I do not know what the mkhwdata function does.
The solution should look something like this:

```
clc
close all;
clear

fc = 0.2;
fs = 1; %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

[z]= mkhwdata([xxxxxxxxx]);

[Z,nu] = tdftfast(z);
%N = length(z);
n = [0:(length(z) - 1)];
%n = N*(0:N-1);
mult  = exp(1i*2*0.25*pi.*n);
mult2 = exp(1i*2*pi*0.5.*n);

% We bring the image to DC
[z1] = (z.*transpose(mult)); 
[z2] = (Z.*transpose(mult2));

%Lowpass filter
[num,den] = butter(9,0.2);

y  = filter(num,den,z);
y1 = filter(num,den,z1);
y2 = filter(num,den,z2);

figure(4)
ylabel('Amplitude');
xlabel('Frequency (hz)');
subplot(221)
present_image(z);
subplot(222)
present_image(y);
subplot(223)
present_image(y1);
subplot(224)
present_image(y2);
```

Comment: Hi I tried with bandpass filter for some reason i was unable to recover the pictures. The mkhwdata function is a vector of images,

Comment: Can you plot the spectrum after the filter? It should appear only the frequencies you are searching for. 
So, z is a vector, a matrix, or what?

Comment: I will try it now , the z is a vector of images, the plot above is the spectrum of z and from that i read the frequency of images. The first image is located at the center around zero and the second at 0.25 and the third at 0.5

Comment: What do you mean by a vector of images? Images of the original frequency or actual images?

Comment: let me add the code of those functions

Comment: By the way, for doing the down conversion it's exp(1i*2*0.25*pi.*n) (without the minus). I have corrected that on the answer

Comment: sorry i accidentally added the details on your answer you delete or not accept  my edit

Comment: Where you able to plot the signal after the bandpass filter? Also I have increased the Bw of the bandpass filter, as I see that the lowpass filter had a higher Bw also

Comment: yes but it gives me some grey pictures which is not recognizable

Comment: Filter the signal with the bandpass, then apply the tdfft function and plot (plot not present_image) the absolute value of it, which would be the frequency spectrum.  You should only see the frequency you are looking for.